# Writing tests that do not fail first

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

TDD best practices say that a fresh test should fail. However, I think it is possible that a test is necessary, although it doesn't fail when it has just been written.

Sample workflow:

1. Write test which checks whether end date goes before start date - test fails;
2. Write code - test passes;

```cs
bool Validate(Condition condition)
{
    if (condition.EndDate <= condition.StartDate)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

3. Refactor - test still passes.

```cs
bool Validate(Condition condition)
{
    return (condition.EndDate > condition.StartDate);
}
```

After step 3 I see that had I not refactored the condition, I could add a new test, which checks that method returns true if start date comes before end date. However, if I do the refactoring first, writing such test would just mean that it passes immediately. To me it looks like the test might make the code more robust.

Why would writing such test would be a bad idea/wouldn't be a good idea according to the TDD?

Edit: I am thinking now, perhaps writing `return true;` by default in the implementation might not be a good idea and I should throw a `NotImplementedException`. Would it be the correct approach in writing code according to the TDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of writing a test that fails is so that every single test is worthwhile. It is just so that you think about your tests, and your code. If you write a test that fails to start with, and then just enough code to make the test pass, then you know that everything you have coded was necessary and adds value to your application.

For instance, taking TDD in its purest form, for the above scenario, if you wanted your first test to test whether or not the method returned true if one date is after another, you could write the test to assert true and just set the method to

```
bool Validate(Condition condition)
{
    return true;
}
```

This would make your first test pass. You would then write another test to assert whether or not the method fails if the end date is before the start date, which would obviously fail. You would then write the code to pass the test, so something like:

```
bool Validate(Condition condition)
{
    return (condition.EndDate > condition.StartDate);
}
```

This means that every bit of code you have written has been necessary, and you know that it behaves exactly as you want it to. This also allows you to break a problem down into steps and handle each stage one at a time. As far as I understand it, that is what TDD is all about.

Comment: Thinking about this problem more, I realized that I violate the principle of writing 'just enough' and go a step further without really thinking about it. The `return true;` probably should have been covered by a unit test before I would write any other tests. Although this example has been made up, it has been more than once that I have faced similar problems. I will try to pay more attention to which amount of code is just right while writing tests. I believe that in my example case, even though the test would pass, I should still write it, otherwise the `return true;` would not be covered.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Red/Green/Refactor is that when you write the test, it shouldn't pass because the functionality doesn't yet exist.  It's the requirements of the test that guide you into writing the passing implementation.

You're looking at a pretty simple case here. An experienced TDD practitioner might look at the problem and skip the test execution step until after writing the code, saving the cost of a compile/test cycle.

On the flip side, there's likely more refactoring to be done.  One thing is the name: Validation.  Validate what? What does it do? How much should it do?  Rename it until it says what it does. Next, you're doing a date comparison on an object outside of that object.  Does the "Condition" class have the responsibility of ensuring the end date follows the start date?  Or is it really a business rule,  associated with the specific use of the Condition?

And don't forget more tests.  What are your requirements?  Can a StartDate be null?  Can a task take less than one day, so can an EndDate and a StartDate be the same?  But if you are comparing minutes and seconds, too, that implies these really are DateTime and not just dates, and shouldn't they therefore be named StartDateTime / EndDateTime?

The goal is not just to produce working software.  The goal is to write readable, understandable, clear software.  The software should act as its own documentation.  TDD can help you by asking the right questions.